# What does calling fit() multiple times on the same model do?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

After I instantiate a scikit model (e.g. `LinearRegression`), if I call its `fit()` method multiple times (with different `X` and `y` data), what happens? Does it fit the model on the data like if I just re-instantiated the model (i.e. from scratch), or does it keep into accounts data already fitted from the previous call to `fit()`?

Trying with `LinearRegression` (also looking at its source code) it seems to me that every time I call `fit()`, it fits from scratch, ignoring the result of any previous call to the same method. I wonder if this true in general, and I can rely on this behavior for all models/pipelines of scikit learn.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If you will execute `model.fit(X_train, y_train)` for a second time - it'll overwrite all previously fitted coefficients, weights, intercept (bias), etc.

If you want to fit just a portion of your data set and then to improve your model by fitting a new data, then you can use [estimators, supporting "Incremental learning" (those, that implement `partial_fit()` method)](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html)

Comment: Some estimators (having the `warm_start` parameter) will reuse the solutions from the previous calls to `fit()` as initial solution in new call when `warm_start = True`.

Comment: @VivekKumar, yes, this is true. But for "linear model" algorithms (like LogisticRegression) the previously fitted coefficients will be used just for the __initialization__ step, so they will/might be overwritten as well

Comment: can we use partial_fit in KNN?

Comment: Broken link, I believe the new location is https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html

Comment: @LeeNeverGup, thank you! I've updated the link in the answer)

Comment: In my case, I want to `IterativeImputer.fit_transform(x)` before I use `model.fit(x,y)`. Is this a good way to use?

Answer (score 8):

You can use term **fit()** and **train()** word interchangeably in machine learning. Based on classification model you have instantiated, may be a `clf = GBNaiveBayes()` or `clf = SVC()`,  your model uses specified machine learning technique.
And as soon as you call `clf.fit(features_train, label_train)` your model starts training using the features and labels that you have passed.

you can use `clf.predict(features_test)` to predict.
If you will again call `clf.fit(features_train2, label_train2)` it will start training again using passed data and will remove the previous results. Your model will **reset** the following inside model:

- Weights
- Fitted Coefficients
- Bias
- And other training related stuff...

You can use **partial_fit()** method as well if you want your previous calculated stuff to stay and additionally train using next data

Comment: I want to implement imputation using IterativeImputer from sklearn, before training the data. To impute the data, I need to `fit_transform` (x-feature) than after that need to `fit ` it again for modelling. Can I use fit again for modelling?  Is this a good method to use?

Answer (score 2):

Beware that the model is passed kind of "by reference". Here, model1 will be overwritten:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100).reshape(10,10))
df2 = df1.copy()
df2.iloc[0,0] = df2.iloc[0,0] -2 # change one value

pca = PCA()
model1 = pca.fit(df)
model2 = pca.fit(df2)

np.unique(model1.explained_variance_ == model2.explained_variance_)
```

Returns

```
array([ True])
```

To avoid this use

```
from copy import deepcopy
model1 = deepcopy(pca.fit(df))
```